# How to Manage static files module in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, project

I've been using Netbeans for a while, but can't find a good way to manage SVN modules that contain only "static" files. Specifically modules that aren't compiled etc. Examples are database scripts or shell scripts that help manage deployments.

Right now what I've done is checked out the module from SVN (ie http://svn/db/trunk), and loaded them into Netbeans as a PHP project. This let's me navigate through the code tree, but it's not ideal.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

--Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not view these "static" files through the Favorites tree (ctrl+3)? Then you don't need to create a NetBeans project, but you can edit them and do source control stuff.

Comment: Sweet... That's exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the folder to the 'Include path' option in Netbeans, either globally or for specific projects. This allows you to access them whilst working on the projects which depend on the code in question, but without the modules being part of a netbeans project.

Comment: I think you must mean the Include Path of a PHP project. I tried that and it works, but it doesn't play nicely with the SVN functionality. For instance, I can load the DB svn module into an include path, and edit files in there, but i can't do a diff on the full directory by right clicking on the folder. Basically i want to be able to edit these scripts like i edit code, so i'd like to be able to commit and interact with SVN also like i do with code.